Multiple stm32 to one external RAM
Is it possible to connect a RAM chip to two stm32? I assume that RAM should act as a data buffer from which the results of calculations can be read.
Or is it better to use the third stm32 to make something like a separate module into which two stm32s will transfer data?
The task is to combine the results of parallel calculations, save them for a while, and then read them all at once.

there is such a thing as a dual port ram

We don't know what your task is and how you are supposed to implement it. Yes you can share a RAM chip, there are many different RAM chips with different buses. Yes there are STM32 chips with megabyte of memory..

Yes it is possible. Specify type of you RAM ... for example with serial RAM (with SPI) it can be siply implemented - you just have to ensure that only one STM will have SPI active at a time.
